# How to store date and time value in a php variable from datetimepicker?

Tags: php, html, datetimepicker

I have implemented two date and time pickers as follows,

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Data</div>

      <div class="col-sm-15">
      <div class="panel-body">
         
       
         <div class="row">

            <div class='col-md-4'>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">From Time</label>
                  <div class='input-group date'>
                     <input type='text' class="form-control" name="from_date" id="from_date" />
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                     </span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">To Time</label>
                  <div class='input-group date'>
                     <input type='text' class="form-control" name="to_date" id="to_date" />
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                     </span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" id='filter'>
         <br /> <br />
         
      </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

After that I have implemented following scripts to get the data and store in a variable.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

      $(function(){
        $('#from_date').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm '
            });
        $('#to_date').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm '
            });
      });     
      $('#filter').click(function(){
                var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
                var to_date = $('#to_date').val();

                $from_date_var=from_date;
                $to_date_var=to_date;
                if( $from_date_var != '' && $to_date_var != '')
                {
                     
                     
                     alert("".$from_date_var);

                }
                else
                {
                     alert("Please Select Date");
                }
           });
    });
</script>
```

But seems like I am not getting the date and time value from `$from_date_var` and  `$to_date_var` , To check this I have implemented a simple alert with `alert("".$from_date_var);` and it only shows undefined. Can someone explain how to store the date and time to variable?

Comment: You haven't done something like `var $from_date_var;` and `var $to_date_var;` thats why they are undefined. i.e.- you haven't defined them. Define those variables before you use them. In fact, there's really no need for those variables at all - you can simply use the ones you have defined already: `from_date` and `to_date`. In terms of using those variables in PHP you will have to send them to your PHP script using Ajax for example.

Comment: alert("".from_date);  also shows as undefined in alertbox.

Comment: Try: `alert(from_date);`

Comment: @SimonK thank you very much. Now works.I am little bit confused why that alert("".from_date); is not working. How should I get then like below?
alert(" You have selected from "from_date" to "to_date); ? like this output?

Comment: Try `alert(" You have selected from " + from_date + " to " + to_date);`

Comment: You seem to be confusing the PHP concatenation operator `.` with Javascript's equivalent `+`

Comment: Now I have reached what I needed.  @SimonK